# Obexd daemon not running

Tags: bluetooth, obex

I am trying to run `obexd` as `daemon` during system startup but when i try to run it manually i get below problem:

```
obexd[5139]: obexd daemon 0.44
Using X11 for dbus-daemon autolaunch was disabled at compile time, set your DBUS
_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS instead
obexd[5139]: manager_init failed
```

Please let me know the solution for this.

Answer (score 2):

i was able to solve following problem using below statement to configure dbus path

export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:path=/var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket"